# Text document unreadable after sudden PC shutdown

Tags: text-processing, encoding, utf-8, mousepad

I was working in a text document with Mousepad, when I accidentally disconnected the power cable, shutting down the computer. When I started my Xubuntu session again, I tried to open the document, but it has become unreadable. When I double click on it, it shows this:

[image]

Even more, Thunar thinks the file type is "Microsoft Help Attribute Definition File" (?), instead of "plain text document". I have tried any encoding available in Mousepad, all of them showing "nonsense".

How can I recover my original document? Is this perhaps a bug of Mousepad?

Comment: Is there a `~` backup? If your file was `/path/to/foo` look for `/path/to/foo~`

Comment: Sadly not. I tried all encoding available in Mousepad. All give "nosense".

Comment: Well, yeah, makes sense if the file is corrupted. Have you tried simply `cat`ing it from the terminal? What does `file filename.txt` show?

Comment: I get "filename: data". The file does not have ".txt" extension. If I open it with `nano` I get same weird code, and below it says "converted from Mac format". `head`, `vi`, and `cat` give the same nosense.